# Opera Mini postMessage

Tags: javascript, iframe, opera, opera-mini

I have a page that creates a simple iframe by JS with

```
document.createElement('iframe');
```

I can them do

```
frames['x'].postMessage(...);
```

Now, since Opera Mini is special I've been trying without luck to make a postMessage to the iframe. Everything I try I have the same exception:

```
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Securiry error: attempted to read protected variable
```

And yes, exceptions happen when I try to do something to fiddle with the frame object.

Anyone has faced this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug on the server-side of the Opera Mini that causes issues with cross-domain postMessage. Fixing it is on our backlog but unfortunately I cannot give an ETA when it will happen. If the iframe you're creating uses content that you supply yourself, you may consider hosting it on the same domain that the main document - this way the postMessage should work as expected - as in this simple testcase: https://dev.opera.com/articles/window-postmessage-messagechannel/crossdocmessaging.html.

Comment: It was fixed a few days ago, cross-domain postMessage should work fine now.